# Data passed as props is not updating in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I can't understand why data passed as props is not updating when data changes. I tried different ways, but for some reason, the frontend knows nothing about data manipulation. Here is my code base:

**For Loop**

```
<SingleElement v-for="addon of addons" :key="addon.id" 
  :id="addon.id"
  :title="addon.name" 
  :description="addon.description"
  :active="addon.active" // This is the part I need to update
></SingleElement>
```

**The SingleElement Template**

```
<template>
  <div class="column is-4">
    <b-field>
      <b-switch v-model="isActive"></b-switch>
    </b-field>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { store, methods } from '../../../store';

export default {
  name: "single-element",
  props: {
    id: Number,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    active: Boolean,
    docURL: String,
    category: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      "isActive" : this.active
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

**The Store**

```
import axios from "axios";

export const store = Vue.observable({
  "addons": [],
  "activatedAddons": [],
  "settings": {}
});

export const methods = {
  activateAllAddons() {
    store.activatedAddons = [];
    for (let addon of store.addons) {
      store.activatedAddons.push(addon.id);
      addon.active = true;
    }
  },
  deactivateAllAddons() {
    store.activatedAddons = [];
    for (let addon of store.addons) {
      addon.active = false;
    }
  },
}
```

The process in short: On click, I call the store method `activateAllAddons` or `deactivateAllAddons`. These methods are changing the `store.activatedAddons` and `store.addons` data. For example I change the `active` boolean. But my switch do not react to this changes. Why?

**What I tried*

I tried to change the data in different ways.

**Way 1**
-> Changing the addon boolean in the store
`:active="addon.active"`

**Way 2**
-> Creating an additional method to check the status:

```
:active="isActive(addon)"
```

and:

```
isActive(addon) {
  return store.activatedAddons.includes(addon.id);
}
```

But no way. The frontend seems to know nothing about the changes. When I log the variables in the console, the changes definitely are there. What's the problem here?

Comment: where did you try printing the console post changing?

Comment: Do you have any getters in the parent Component (where you have the `<SingleElement />`) so that you could get the updated value of `addons`?

Comment: I've checked the state of the store.activatedAddons in the store itself after changing them with `activateAllAddons()` for example. I setup no additional getters. I found a workaround with a watcher in the SingleElement itself checking for the `active` prop. When new changes are there, I set `this.isActive = newValue;`. Do you think this is a clean solution?

Comment: Ya so it means the prop values are getting updated in the child component, right?

Comment: We shouldn't bind the prop value directly to a v-model, hence you are using a local variable `isActive`. So in this approach, `watch` is only way to detect change and reassign the new value.

Comment: Ok, so I can sleep well with this way to update the value and it is not a quick and dirty solution? :-)

Comment: As far as I know, this is the way. Maybe lets see what other experts say

Comment: How do you retrieve the store values ?